# Prevent a string with from being cast to an int with try/catch

Tags: c++, vector

I am using try/catch exception to sort a vector of strings and I want to prevent it from converting a string like "157cm" from being converted to an int. It removes the "cm" part.
Is there anyway to prevent this?

My code:

```
  for (int v = 0; v < values.data.size(); v++) {
        
        try
        {
            int value = std::stod(values.data.at(v));
            values.areints2.push_back(value);
         
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            string x;
            x = values.data.at(v);
            values.notints2.push_back(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a significant abuse of exceptions. C++exceptions are not designed to be used for normal flow control.

Comment: Duplicate applies to `stod` the same way it does to `stoi`. (From the looks of it you want to use `stoi` instead of `stod` here anyway, since you store the `double` returned by `stod` to an `int`.)

Comment: *"Is there any way to prevent this?"* - Prevent *what* ? The conversion, or the expulsion of `"cm"` whilst doing so? If the latter, what would you suggest `cm` be converted *to* ? Regarding the actual conversion(s), first, `std::stod` does't do integer conversion; it's does `double` conversion. Second, review the documentation for [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). You'll find there are arguments (looking at you, `pos`) that will *probably* help you detect where things stopped parsing vs. where you hoped they would.

Comment: `strtol` is a much better fit here.  It (a) reports failure through an output parameter not an exception and (b) reports leftover data through the same output parameter.